# Java Bluej instances does not display print

Tags: java, bluej

I am using bluej to make a program for userlists.
When i compile and run the code bluej does not give anny errors.
But when i make a new instance of a class it looks like nothing happens.
Printing a line to my terminal window from my instance does not work.
How can i make my instance print show in my terminal window?

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.text.*;

   public class Main{
       private ArrayList<List> userlists;
       public Main(){
          System.out.print('\f');
          System.out.println("this text will show.");
          newlist("listname");
       }
       public void newlist(String listname){
          System.out.println("this text will show too!");
          List userlist = new List(listname); //terminal does not show lines printed by constructor of List?
          userlists.add(userlist);
          userlist.printSomeText(); //second attempt to print a line, does not show in terminal.
       }
    }

    public class List {
        private String listname;
        public List(String ln) {
            listname = ln;
            System.out.println("this text does not show.");
        }
        public void printSomeText(){
            System.out.println("this text neither.");      
        }
    }
```

I Run this by (first compiling both classes and then) rightclicking on the Main class in bluej's interface and choosing new Main(). When i do this a terminal window shows up showing:

```
this text will show.
this text will show too!
```

but it does not show:

```
this text will show.
this text will show too!
this text does not show.
this text neither.
```

It does not show anny error's so i would like to know whats going wrong and how to get the second result, showing those four lines.

Comment: your class doesnt have a pulic static void main method ??

Comment: No it does not, didn't really understand the use of it becouse in the interface of bluej i can just right click on a class file (or java file) and click on new Main(); It did exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you dont have two `public` class in the same `Java` file.

Second you must have to initialize the variable before using that variable or field, which is not happening in your question. I have done some modification in your code that will work according to you and also print the second bunch of lines, which you want to print.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    private ArrayList<List> userlists;

    public Main() {
        userlists = new ArrayList<List>();
        System.out.print('\f');
        System.out.println("this text will show.");
        newlist("listname");
    }

    public void newlist(String listname) {
        System.out.println("this text will show too!");
        List userlist = new List(listname); // terminal does not show lines
                                            // printed by constructor of List?
        userlists.add(userlist);
        userlist.printSomeText(); // second attempt to print a line, does not
                                    // show in terminal.
    }

    public static void main(String ... args){
        new Main();
    }
}

class List {
    private String listname;

    public List(String ln) {
        listname = ln;
        System.out.println("this text does not show.");
    }

    public void printSomeText() {
        System.out.println("this text neither.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't be confused by

```
public Main() {
   ...
}
```

This is a *constructor*. You'll need a `main` method entry point to call this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new Main();
}
```

*Aside*: Don't forget to instantiate your `userlists` `ArrayList` to avoid getting an `NPE`:

```
private ArrayList<List> userlists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! BlueJ did not construct the instance becouse it was still building the mainclass i supose fixed this by adding the static method which first build the class and then runs a bunch of code.